# Restrictions on an array of numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

We have an array of numbers. The mean of these numbers is $200$. $X$ is the largest element and $Y$ is the smallest one. We have to satisfy $X=3+2Y$. There's no limit on the size of the array (the amount of elements it contains).

I want to find out which numbers couldn't appear in the array.

Since the smallest element have to be lesser than $200$ (so the mean can be $200$), than the largest number have to be lesser than $3+2*200=403$.

My question is: are there any other restrictions on the numbers that could appear in the array?

Comment: Suppose you have two numbers, $y$ and $x=3+2y$. Their mean is $200$ thus $\frac{3+2y + y}{2}=200\to y=132.33;\;x=267.67$.

Comment: Yes, this is the case if there are only two numbers in the array. But there's no restriction on the quantity of numbers. What I'm trying to figure out is if there are any other restrictions on which numbers could appear in the array, other than the restriction that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working over the integers temporarily, you could have $Y = 99$ so that $X = 201$.  The array consisting of 99 (once) and 201 repeated 101 times has mean 200.

At the other extreme, you could have $Y = 199$ so that $X = 401$.  The array consisting of 199 repeated 201 times and a single 401 has mean 200.

Switching to the reals, you choose $Y$ so that $X$ is greater 200 by an arbitrarily small amount and make an array with mean 200.  Similarly, you can choose $Y$ less than 200 by an arbitrarily small amount and make an array with mean 200.

Are there other kinds of restrictions you were hoping for?

---

Subsequent addition. Following up on the previous comments gives bounds for $X$ and $Y$:

It's clear that no $Y \ge 200$ could work as the smallest number in a list with mean 200 (since a larger $X$ has to be included). Since any $Y < 200$ can work, that gives $X = 3 + 2Y < 403$.

Similarly you cannot have $X \le 200$ as the largest number of a list with mean 200.  Since any $X>200$ can work, the equivalent expression $Y = (X-3)/2$ gives $Y > 197/2 = 98.5$.

Comment: I've been told that there is another(s) restriction(s), but I'm starting to feel it's not true.

Comment: I think it's just $98.5 < y < 200$ and $200 < x < 403$ with the outside restraints coming from $x = 3 + 2y$ relation.

Comment: where did this constrains come from, @Brian ?

Comment: I mean, why the number 98.5? @Brian